# Where should websites live on Centos servers?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos5

I am re-organising some web servers, the majority of which are running the Centos linux distro.

Each of these servers has multiple sites being served using virtual hosts.

Is there a "correct" place that the source for each of these sites should be kept?

The two main options seem to be in /home and /var/www

eg

/home/
/home/

or

/var/www/
/var/www/

Whilst I know it doesn't make a massive difference, the aim of re-organising these servers is to get everything standardised so I would like to know of any reasons as to why one of these may be preferred over the other or if there is a "normal" way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [File System Hierachy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.txt.gz) `/srv/www` would be correct. It is for data that is served by the system.

Comment: Not *necessarily* `/srv/www` specifically, but certainly somewhere under `/srv`.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use `/var/www/html` for single sites, or `/var/www/sitename` for multiple site setups. It's fairly consistent and CentOS/RHEL points you in that direction...

Comment: installing apache on centos will defaultly use /var/www/html.